# Solving $\frac{\ 3x}{x^2+x+1}+\frac{2x}{x^2-x+1}=3$ with other approaches

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $$\frac{\ 3x}{x^2+x+1}+\frac{2x}{x^2-x+1}=3$$
>
> $$x=?$$

I solved this problem as follow:

$x=0$ is not a root, we  can divide numerator and denominator of each fraction by $x$:

$$\frac{3}{t+1}+\frac{2}{t-1}=3\quad\quad\text{where $t=x+\frac1x$}$$

$$5t-1=3t^2-3\Rightarrow t=2 , \frac{-1}6$$

Only $x+\frac1x=2$ is acceptable and $x=1$.

I'm looking for other elegant methods to solve this equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $(x-1)^2\ge 0$ with equality if and only of $x=1$.

But
\begin{align}
(x-1)^2 \ge 0 &\iff x^2-2x+1\ge 0\\
&\iff x^2+x+1\ge 3x\\
&\iff \frac{3x}{x^2+x+1}\le 1
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
(x-1)^2 \ge 0 &\iff x^2-2x+1\ge 0\\
&\iff x^2-x+1\ge x\\
&\iff \frac{x}{x^2-x+1}\le 1\\
&\iff \frac{2x}{x^2-x+1}\le 2
\end{align}

Then $$\frac{3x}{x^2+x+1} + \frac{2x}{x^2-x+1} \le 3$$

with equality if and only if $x=1$.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you consider this elegant:

\begin{align}
0&=3-\frac{3x}{x^2+x+1}-\frac{2x}{x^2-x+1}\\
&=\left(1-\frac{3x}{x^2+x+1}\right)+2\left(1-\frac{x}{x^2-x+1}\right)\\
&=\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^2+x+1}+2\frac{(x-1)^2}{x^2-x+1}\\
&=(x-1)^2\left(\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}+\frac{2}{x^2-x+1}\right)
\end{align}

Since $x^2+x+1$ and $x^2-x+1$ are always positive, we can cancel the second part to get $(x-1)^2=0$